# Django - SubQuery e function F()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have 2 models (author and book). I want to annotate in the author model the highest book price for every authors (in order to manipulate it later). I would like to make a query with an internal sub-query using the F() function but the problem is that the F() is refered to the book model but I would like to refer it to the author model. I'll show that with an example. The models are shown below:

```
class author:
    authorID = models.AutoField(primary_key = True, auto_created = True, unique = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class book:
    ownerID = models.ForeignKey(author, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='hook')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

The query in question is as follows:

```
value = author.objects.annotate(maxPrice = (book.objects.filter(ownerID = F('authorID')).order_by('-price') [0]))
```

F('authorID') is refered to the book DB and so Django returns an error but I want to refer it to the author DB to achieve my goal. How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use a SubQuery? You can use the [Max](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#max) function on the related_name for this annotation - `Author.objects.annotate(max_price=Max('hook__price'))`

Comment: Because I have shown a simplified example just to know how to refer F() function to the first model. The real algorithm is more complex tha calculating maximum.

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of `F('authorID')` you need to use `OuterRef('authorID')`